# Create an state array of another state array length in react

Tags: reactjs, arrays, axios

I'm trying to create a layout for pizza toppings and For this, I'm creating an array which will be used to sum up the price of the toppings used for the pizza. But I'm able to get the length of the toppings array to create an array of the same length.

```
constructor(){
  super();
  this.state = {
    ingredients:[],
    array:new Array(ingredients.length).fill(false)
  };
}

componentDidMount =()=> {
  axios.get("https://localhost:2000/toppings")
    .then((response) => this.setState({
       ingredients: response.data
    })).catch(err => console.log(err))
}
```

After running this I'm getting `'ingredients' is not defined` in the console. Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just curious - cant you just set the `array` inside the `setState` within `componentDidMount`?

Comment: 'Ingredients' is capitalized, maybe you accidently wrote it with an uppercase i?

Comment: I did set the `array` inside `setState` but still getting the same error

Comment: @Mart I made a typo here

Comment: Are you accessing `ingredients` other places in the code, and if so are you accessing `this.state.ingredients`?

Comment: @Mart I'm accessing `ingredients` in the way you mentioned. I updated the same with the `array` declaration and it worked.